# "Invalid Client" with Auth0 and Sign In With Apple

Tags: react-native, auth0, apple-sign-in

I've implemented Sign in With Apple with Auth0 on iOS with react-native-auth0 but I am getting the following error when I attempt to sign in:

"Invalid Client"

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what might be misconfigured etc.  Has anyone else run into this?

Using react-native-auth0@2.5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the correct configuration elements are in place, both in the Auth0 Management Dashboard and in the Apple Developer Settings Console. Common configuration problems include:

- Using the wrong identifier: Remember that Apple App IDs (also known
  as App Bundle Identifiers) need to be configured in Auth0's advanced
  application settings. Service IDs, which are used to configure web
  apps, need to be configured in connection settings. Switching these
  identifiers will result in failures.

More info here: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/apple-siwa/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks - what it was was that I misunderstood that "Client ID" in Auth0 is a "Service ID" in Apple parlance.  Correcting this Client ID to be the Apple Service ID fixed it.